# What the best choose in archiving individual and total group of file?

Tags: compression, archiving

If I suppose I have N files with different sizes.
If I use a compression algorithm, like ZIP or 7ZIP for example, is there any difference in size between archiving individually files compressed and the all compressed files?

In other words, if f(i) is a i-file, and C(f(i)) = file compressed is true that:

size of [C( f(1), f(2), ... , f(n))] == size of [C(f(1)) + ... + C(f(n))]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files have some similarity then there can be a noticeable advantage to a "solid" archive, which is putting the files together in a sequence and compressing them as one big file, like a `.tar.gz` file, as opposed to compressing each file individually, like `.zip`.

The advantage is even greater if the files are small.

I just did a quick test on a small set of files, where the `.tar.gz` was 15% smaller than a `.zip` file with the same contents.  Both were compressed with the same compression algorithm at the same compression level.

Answer (score 0):

There's the zip headers to consider. That'll be some number of bytes, plus the per-file overhead as well. No idea what the real numbers are, but making up some figures:

```
100 bytes - zip overhead
10 bytes - per-zipped file data

10 files, each zipped invidually: 10x100 + 10x10 = 1100 bytes overhead
10 files, all in a single zip file: 1x100 + 10x10 = 200 bytes overhead
```

And that's totally ignoring any efficiencies from being able to create "tighter" compression alphabets from the larger datasets of having all 10 files in a single .zip.